# CSS3 animation only works on the first hover

Tags: html, css, animate.css

I am building a website and i am attempting to animate a `:hover` of a div so that when a mouse hovers over it another div that is currently at `opacity:0` will increase its opacity to `0.8` over the span of 3.5 seconds while concurrently fading down into place.

This will work properly until the second time that i try it and then it will not fade back to `0` opacity when i leave the object with my mouse. The object will stay visible with opacity `0.8`.

Hopefully i am making sense.

The fade animations are pulled from Animate.css and inserted directly into my css.

All of my code pertaining to this issue can be found here

```
.widget-Button4.widget-header.widget-html-widget.widget p
{
  background:none;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 1000px;
}

#Hosting
{
  background-image: url("images/header_rollout_expandedbg.png");
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.538em;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 14px 14px 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 274px;
  left: 909px;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-animation:fadeOutUp 3.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation:fadeOutUp 3.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opactiy 3.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in-out;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

#HostingButton
{
  background-image: url("images/header_rolloutbg_static_complete.png");
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 263px;
  left: 1007px;
  -webkit-transition: all 3.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 3.5s ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition: all 3.5s ease-in-out; 
  -ms-transition: all 3.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 50;
}

#HostingButton:hover
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(1080deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(1080deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(1080deg);
}

#HostingButton:hover + #Hosting
{
  -webkit-animation:fadeInDown 3.5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation:fadeInDown 3.5s;
  transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown
{
    0%
{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
100%
{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
}

@keyframes fadeInDown
{
0%
{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
100%
{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutUp
{
0%
{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
100%
{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}

}

@keyframes fadeOutUp
{
0%
{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
100%
{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
}
```

And the HTML to go along with it here

```
<p>
    Hosting
</p>
<div id="HostingButton">
</div>
<div id="Hosting">
    <div id="rollouttext">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

I managed to get the opacity part of it that i am having trouble with working in JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/7uR8z/1499/

It is the same code that i am using however, i think i might have some conflict and i am having a hell of a time trying to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you are describing it is where there are 2 divs. The first div is visible and the second div is 0 opacity. When you hover the first div is 0 opacity and the second div is 80% opacity. This happens over 3.5 seconds.

I made the 2 states in different divs .item and .description. Not too sure why you had zoom in there? Let me know if this is not what you're trying to do.

```
.container {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
}
.item {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opactiy 3.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.item:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
.descriton {
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:green;
    display:visible;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opactiy 3.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 3.5s ease-in;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
.descriton:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Check out the demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDHss/)

Comment: Both states are going to be applied to the single #hosting div.

The original JSFiddle i posted with the question actually has the correct end result that i am looking for. However when i use that exact code it does not emulate what happens in JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/7uR8z/1499/


And also, i am not sure how that zoom line got in there to be honest with you. I noticed it earlier and took it out but it still ended up in the question.

Comment: Sorry I was confused on the wording. Knowing that the fiddle works, what else is the end result supposed to look like that isn't in the fiddle?

Comment: Well i am using the unmodified functions from Animate.css for fadeindown and fadeupout. Those are combined with the animation in the jsfiddle.

So what ends up happening is the box with text in it will fadeindown and change opacity to 80% when the first div is hovered over. When the hover is no longer active it will return to its original state using a fadeupout and opacity change to 0. After it has completed this it will reappear using no animation with 80% opacity again.

Comment: The issue might also be something to do with my environment. My friend who visited the code in use says that it displays properly on his machine and according to him he is using the same browser/version that i am. Chrome Version 29.0.1547.66 m

Comment: I understand the problem now. mmhm, is he viewing the jfiddle or all your files with animate.css? ill download animate.css and see what happens. Let you know in a bit.

Comment: He is viewing the site live as a user would. I think i might have figured out the issue and i am trying to troubleshoot it right now. I believe it is an issue with the multiple uses of transition in an attempt to make it cross browser compatible. I believe two of the transition effects are in use at the same time when i run it live.

Comment: I am not sure who changed the title of the question but the title is now inaccurate. I have found the issue with the animation. Both the animation i set on the div in an attempt to hide it on page load (the JSFiddle code) and the Animate.css fadeupout are both attempting to change the opacity back to 0. For some reason this ends up with the div being placed back to 0.8 opacity. (Not sure why). I am trying to rework the code to hide the div on load so this interaction does not happen anymore.

Comment: I am happy that may you have figured out the problem. With what you have originally posted above, I think there is no problem when I am viewing it. Check out this video recording. http://youtu.be/XBupifOIZO0

Comment: Yeah that is the desired effect. And that is what my friend also witnessed. I just now need the div to come in as opacity 0 to start with instead of making an animation to do it :) I am not sure how i overlooked that so drastically.